# How to fill a complex countour in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

> Scenario

I am writing a program to detect hair from skin. So far, I have done this...

1. Loaded source image and applied grabcut to remove background

[image]

2. Applied skin detection to obtain skin

[image]

3. Performed ANDing to obtain Hair, along with other regions

[image]

4. Ran contour detection to obtain contour with maximum size

[image]

```
Imgproc.drawContours(mask, contours, maxAreaIndex, new Scalar(255,255,255),1);
```

> Problem

When I try to fill my mask obtained by running findContour using code

```
Imgproc.drawContours(mask, contours, maxAreaIndex, new Scalar(255,255,255),Core.FILLED);
```

it fills the contour like

[image]

Now, I cannot use this as a mask since it will produce my result as

[image]

which is not what I want.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve a filled contour for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply some dilation-erosion (closing) filtering before extracting the contours to be sure that you get a full contour. Essentially, what dilation-erosion does is closes contour areas that would normally be separate that are near each other by expanding them so that they intersect, then shrinking the now intersected contour back down so that it remains correctly scaled. Check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) for more information on this topic.

HOWEVER, this method assumes that you have detected mostly the hair in your image. What you have done is different; you have detected the NOT SKIN in your picture, and assumed that the hair was the largest contour. By doing this, when you close your contours, especially on images where the person's shirt is higher cut, you may run in to some issue where you are detecting the shirt and the hair. I would add an additional step in your pipeline where you attempt to segment out the shirt on the person before applying this filtering.

Good Luck!